# Different output from a function with the same arguments

Tags: python

Why is my function 'increment' return different values for matrix that i create by other function and different for manual matrix?

```
n = 2
m = 3
indices = [[0,1],[1,1]]

def matrixpopulation(n,m):
    row=[]
    matrix=[]
    row+=(0  for _ in range(0,m))            
    matrix+=(row for _ in range(0,n))
    return matrix

def increment(indices,matrixa):
    for v,k in indices:
        for i in range(3):
            matrixa[v][i]+=1
        for i in range(2):  
            matrixa[i][k]+=1
    return matrixa

matrixa=matrixpopulation(n,m)
filled_matrix=increment(indices,matrixa)

print(matrixpopulation(n,m))
print(filled_matrix)

manualmatrix=[[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
print(manualmatrix)
print(increment(indices,manualmatrix))
```

Comment: Please also add the output of your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
matrix+=(row for _ in range(0,n))
```

When you make matrix here you actually add the reference to the same `row` n-times. When you modify some element in one 'row', all other rows are modified as well. For example:

```
a = [1, 2]
b = [a, a]
a[0] = 3
```

Check `b` now.